# Can't remove a column in my footer

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am starting a wordpress page and I am trying to remove the right column in my footer but it does not work. Can you please help me on this?

The code of my footer.php is pretty long, but I think that the issue is in the first part of the code:

```
<!-- footer -->
        <div class="footer_container_full">
        <footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
            <div class="footer_container">
            <div class="footer-widget">
    <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-footer')) ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

            </div>
            <!-- copyright -->
            <div class="footer_copyright_full">
            <div class="footer_copyright">
            <a class="back_to_top" href="#top">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </a>
                <div class="copyrights">
                <?php
                 $copy=ot_get_option('footer_copyrights');
                 if($copy) : echo $copy; 
                 else : echo '&copy;&nbsp;'.date("Y").'&nbsp;Copyright&nbsp;'.get_bloginfo('name').' / Logo: Andrii_M, Shutterstock.com. <br />PRIVACY: We will never disclose or sell your email address or any of your data from this site. <br /> DISCLAIMER: Blabla exists to thought provoke and learn from the community. Your decisions are yours alone and we are in no way responsible for your actions. In short, think twice before making any financial transaction!
Please read our Disclosures and Terms Of Use';
                 endif;
                ?>
                <div class="clear"></div> 

            </div>
            <!-- /copyright -->
            </div>

        </footer>
        </div>
        <!-- /footer -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!--2-container-->
```

Comment: Which element is the right column?

Comment: The left column is the one with text. There was a RSS icon in the right one , I have been able to delete the icon but not the column unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried `display: none` on the column?

Comment: Thanks Michael, how can I do this? I can't find the name of that column section in the code

Comment: That's what I was asking. Go into dev tools and right click on the column. It will show you the element.

Comment: Excellent, I just discovered Dev tools! so it seems that the name is 2_container

Comment: Hmmm I am not sure in fact. What I am sure is that the column that I want to keep is called "copyrights". Maybe there is no name for the other one?

Comment: Do you have a live site?

Comment: Not yet, it is not developed enough to be live

Comment: Maybe you can reproduce the problem in jsfiddle.net or codepen.io. Post the link if possible.

Comment: Thank for your help Michael, I might work on other parts and get live so that I can get help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the element you want to hide and apply `display: none` in the CSS. With `display: none` applied, it's as though the element doesn't exist, in terms of visual media. Screen readers and other assistive technology may still pick it up because they may not look at the CSS.

Comment: Hello, my website is now live and I still have this issue with my footer can someone help me? www.gladiatorinvestor.com/

Comment: What is it you want to do in the footer?

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for your reply. I don't know why, the footer is displayed in one column on the left. The right column is empty. I don't need columns

Comment: How exactly do you want it to look?

Comment: I would like it to be centered and take the full width of the page. Only one column, not 2

Comment: Okay. I only see one column. But do this: From `.footer_copyright .copyrights` remove `float: left` and `width 50%`.

Comment: Worked when I removed them in dev tools, assuming I understand what you're after. Can you post a screenshot of how it's supposed to look?

Comment: Could it be in .single h1 ?

Comment: That's exactly the result of the code adjustment I posted above.

Comment: Ha ok. But i adjusted the css code: .footer_copyright .copyrights {
 text-transform: uppercase!important;
 font-size: 10pt;
}

Comment: Works here. Not sure what the problem is. But that picture is the result of removing those two rules.

Comment: And when you onto my website, do you see it this way too?

Comment: I was on your website. That's where the screenshot is from. I just removed those two rules using Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Because I removed them too but it still shows up on the left on my computer. with an empty column on the right. Weird

Comment: It seems to work on my phone and it works, maybe it is an issue with Wordpress. Anyway, many thanks Michael!